# Price calculator by each hour

Tags: php, knockout.js, momentjs

I'm making a pricing calculator that adds up the difference between two dates.
The standard price is $500.00 for a certain amount of hours (example would be 3 hours). If the difference is over that minimum hour, you add an extra $100.00 to the standard price.

I used PHP to generate the Price in an email when the Total time is posted.

// HTML

```
<label>Start Date &amp; Time</label>

<input type="datetime" id="time2" name="start" data-bind="value: start, valueUpdate:'keyup'" required="required" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS am or pm">

<label class="label">End Date &amp; Time</label>
<input type="datetime" id="time1" name="end" data-bind="value: end, valueUpdate:'keyup'" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS am or pm" required="required">

<label class="label">Time Total:</label>
<input type="text" name="difference" id="difference" data-bind="value: difference">
```

The Difference is generated dynamically with Moment.js and Knockout keyup.

```
// PHP
<?php
     $start = $_POST['start'];
     $end = $_POST['end'];
     $difference = (int)$_GET['difference'];

// Time Calculator
$standardRate = 500;
$addhour = 100;
$minimum = 3;

if ($difference > $minimum) {
    $hour = $difference - $minimum;
    return $standardRate = ceil($hour * $addHour) + $standardRate;
} else {
    return $standardRate;
}

$email_content .= "Price: $standardRate\n\n";

?>
```

Am I doing the calculation correctly?

Comment: Have you tested it? If you think something looks wrong, you should also specify why.

Comment: no need to return anything in if or else block

Comment: I have tested it. I only get the amount of hour s but not the price calculated.

Comment: I was able to make output the standard price, but it doesn't add the additional $100 for each hour.